# Why is fprintf Giving Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, networking, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write this function that will create an HTML document that I can write a 404 error message in, with the file name given in the function parameter.

The `fprintf` call is giving me segmentation fault, core dump though.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
void notFoundResponse(int clientSocket, char* fileName){
    char response[30] = {"HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n\n"};
    char buffer[256];
    FILE* file = fopen("404.html", "w+");
    
    fprintf(file, "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Found</H1>The requested URL %s was not found on this server.<P>\r\n" , fileName);
    write(clientSocket, response, strlen(response) + 1);
    fread(buffer, 256, 1, file);
    write(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);
    
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: You need to `fclose/fopen` or `rewind` the file file before reading from it again. And always check the return value of functions. You'll probably find `fread` returns 0.

Comment: Or `fopen` may have failed and returned `NULL`, Again, add proper error checking.

Comment: `strlen(buffer)` is questionable as it is lacks a null character.

Comment: For (e.g.) `write(clientSocket, response, strlen(response) + 1);` will send a binary 0x00 at the end. Are you sure that's what you want? For most parts of `http`, that would confuse the recipient. I'd do: `write(clientSocket, response, strlen(response));`

Answer (score 0):

is there more information?

try to modify the `char response[30] = {"HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n\n"};` to `char response[64] = "HTTP/1.0 404 \r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"`

Maybe you didn't specify the Content-type, so the HTTP connection closed after you sent the response. I think you should specify Content-type to tell the client that you will send a html file later.

**If you are very sure that it is a fprintf segfault, please ignore my answer.**

If my answer is seriously wrong, please comment and let me know that I will delete the answer.